# invoke text/aria-label gives object instead of text

Tags: cypress, element

im trying to invoke the text/aria-label from an element but i get an object:

the element:

```
<p class="styles_startingColumn__8EIiq" data-cy="listValues_popup_txt" aria-label="1+" data-mui-internal-clone-element="true">1+</p>
```

the code :

```
getFirstValueInList() {
        return cy.get("[data-cy='listValues_popup_txt']").should('be.visible').eq(0).invoke('attr','aria-label');
}


 getFirstValueInList() {
        return cy.get("[data-cy='listValues_popup_txt']").should('be.visible').eq(0).invoke('text');
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the log of the returned object?

Comment: What precisely are you trying to do with the text/aria-label?

Answer (score 5):

The Cypress commands are asynchronous.

Get the return value of your functions using `.then()` callback.

```js
getFirstValueInList().then(value => 
  expect(value).to.eq('1+')
})
```

Assertions are via `.should()` command.

```js
getFirstValueInList().should('eq', '+1')
```

---

If you want async/await, you can wrap result in a Promise

```js
getFirstValueInList() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    cy.get("[data-cy='listValues_popup_txt']")
      .should('be.visible').eq(0)
      .invoke('attr','aria-label')
      .then(ariaLabel => resolve(ariaLabel))  // here changes command to promise
  }) 
}

...

it('tests aria label', async () => {
  const ariaLabel = await getFirstValueInList()
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `return` a Cypress command, it will return an object of type `Chainable<T>`. In your case, this would be `Chainable<String>`. This is done so that Cypress commands are easily chainable, and can pass objects between commands.

If you needed to run an assertion after getting the value, you could simply chain another command off of this command.

```js
getFirstValueInList()
  .should('have.text', 'foo');
```

If you needed to store the text/aria-label value for later, you could modify your command to use Cypress environment variables.

```js
getFirstValueInList() {
    return cy.get("[data-cy='listValues_popup_txt']")
         .should('be.visible')
         .eq(0)
         .invoke('attr','aria-label')
         .then((ariaLabel) => {
           Cypress.env('ariaLabel', ariaLabel);
         });

}
...
getFirstValueInList()
  .then(() => {
    cy.log(Cypress.env('ariaLabel'));
  });
```